# recording an audio , submit it ,store it in the server , and store it path in a database. Laravel

Tags: laravel, audio-recording

can someone please help me.
I need to record audio in my browser and submit it to a server so that it can store it and store it path in the database.

i found this tutorial -> https://addpipe.com/simple-recorderjs-demo/
and i use the source code as follows :

```
<form action="{{route('X')}}" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<div id="controls">
    <button id="recordButton">Record</button>
    <button id="pauseButton" disabled>Pause</button>
    <button id="stopButton" disabled>Stop</button>
    </div>
    <div id="formats">Format: start recording to see sample rate</div>
    <p><strong>Recordings:</strong></p>
    <ol id="recordingsList"></ol>
    <!-- inserting these scripts at the end to be able to use all the elements in the DOM -->

</form>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/08e7abd9/dist/recorder.js"></script>
<script >
//webkitURL is deprecated but nevertheless
URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var gumStream;                      //stream from getUserMedia()
var rec;                            //Recorder.js object
var input;                          //MediaStreamAudioSourceNode we'll be recording

// shim for AudioContext when it's not avb. 
var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var audioContext //audio context to help us record

var recordButton = document.getElementById("recordButton");
var stopButton = document.getElementById("stopButton");
var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pauseButton");

//add events to those 2 buttons
recordButton.addEventListener("click", startRecording);
stopButton.addEventListener("click", stopRecording);
pauseButton.addEventListener("click", pauseRecording);

function startRecording() {
    console.log("recordButton clicked");

    /*
        Simple constraints object, for more advanced audio features see
        https://addpipe.com/blog/audio-constraints-getusermedia/
    */

    var constraints = { audio: true, video:false }

    /*
        Disable the record button until we get a success or fail from getUserMedia() 
    */

    recordButton.disabled = true;
    stopButton.disabled = false;
    pauseButton.disabled = false

    /*
        We're using the standard promise based getUserMedia() 
        https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia
    */

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
        console.log("getUserMedia() success, stream created, initializing Recorder.js ...");

        /*
            create an audio context after getUserMedia is called
            sampleRate might change after getUserMedia is called, like it does on macOS when recording through AirPods
            the sampleRate defaults to the one set in your OS for your playback device

        */
        audioContext = new AudioContext();

        //update the format 
        document.getElementById("formats").innerHTML="Format: 1 channel pcm @ "+audioContext.sampleRate/1000+"kHz"

        /*  assign to gumStream for later use  */
        gumStream = stream;

        /* use the stream */
        input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

        /* 
            Create the Recorder object and configure to record mono sound (1 channel)
            Recording 2 channels  will double the file size
        */
        rec = new Recorder(input,{numChannels:1})

        //start the recording process
        rec.record()

        console.log("Recording started");

    }).catch(function(err) {
        //enable the record button if getUserMedia() fails
        recordButton.disabled = false;
        stopButton.disabled = true;
        pauseButton.disabled = true
    });
}

function pauseRecording(){
    console.log("pauseButton clicked rec.recording=",rec.recording );
    if (rec.recording){
        //pause
        rec.stop();
        pauseButton.innerHTML="Resume";
    }else{
        //resume
        rec.record()
        pauseButton.innerHTML="Pause";

    }
}

function stopRecording() {
    console.log("stopButton clicked");

    //disable the stop button, enable the record too allow for new recordings
    stopButton.disabled = true;
    recordButton.disabled = false;
    pauseButton.disabled = true;

    //reset button just in case the recording is stopped while paused
    pauseButton.innerHTML="Pause";

    //tell the recorder to stop the recording
    rec.stop();

    //stop microphone access
    gumStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();

    //create the wav blob and pass it on to createDownloadLink
    rec.exportWAV(createDownloadLink);
}

function createDownloadLink(blob) {

    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var au = document.createElement('audio');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    //name of .wav file to use during upload and download (without extendion)
    var filename = new Date().toISOString();

    //add controls to the <audio> element
    au.controls = true;
    au.src = url;

    //save to disk link
    link.href = url;
    link.download = filename+".wav"; //download forces the browser to donwload the file using the  filename
    link.innerHTML = "Save to disk";

    //add the new audio element to li
    li.appendChild(au);

    //add the filename to the li
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(filename+".wav "))

    //add the save to disk link to li
    li.appendChild(link);

    //upload link
    var upload = document.createElement('a');
    upload.href="X";
    upload.innerHTML = "Upload";
    upload.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
        //   var xhr=new HttpRequest();
        xhr.onload=function(e) {
            if(this.readyState === 4) {
                console.log("Server returned: ",e.target.responseText);
            }
        };
        var fd=new FormData();
        fd.append("audio_data",blob, filename);
        xhr.open("POST","upload.php",true);
        xhr.send(fd);
    })
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode (" "))//add a space in between
    li.appendChild(upload)//add the upload link to li

    //add the li element to the ol
    recordingsList.appendChild(li);
}
</script>
```

and in the same directory i past the upload.php that contains

```
    <?php
print_r($_FILES); //this will print out the received name, temp name, type, size, etc.


$size = $_FILES['audio_data']['size']; //the size in bytes
$input = $_FILES['audio_data']['tmp_name']; //temporary name that PHP gave to the uploaded file
$output = $_FILES['audio_data']['name'].".wav"; //letting the client control the filename is a rather bad idea

//move the file from temp name to local folder using $output name
move_uploaded_file($input, $output)
?>
```

and this is my route :

```
Route::post('X' , 'DM\Conseil@store')->name('X');
```

AND THIS THE CONTROLLER :

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    // dd($request);
    dd($request->file);
}
```

PS : i disabled the csrf token on this route because it will cause problem whene submiting the form.

the audio is recorded successfully BUT after the upload to the serve ; the dd($request->file); gives me a NULL any idea how to fix it please.

Answer (score 1):

`$request->file` not return anything because you don't hava a field name as file. You should use:

```
$file = $request->file('audio_data');
```

OR

```
$file = $request->audio_data;
```

Comment: thank you bro ,but it didn't work ; it still showing NULL